# Find the exact occurrence of a substring in a string SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to know how we can find the exact occurence of a substring in a string. To be more specific the string has words seperated by commas and I want to know if a word exists exactly or not.

Let's say we have something like this:

```
DECLARE @VisitedWebParts nvarchar(255)

 SET @VisitedWebParts =  'MyNavContacts,MyNavUpcomingMaturities,MyNavActivitySummary,MyNavCompanies,CompanyNavBidHistory,CompanyNav'
```

How do I find lets say if 'CompanyNav' existed in the string. Using Like or CharIndex may not help and correct me if I wrong because that would also falsely say CompanyNav would exist if CompanyNav did not actually exist and CompanyNavBidHis exists. You know what I mean!

Thanks in advance for ideas and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to make sure that you consider the commas on either side of the string as well. Which means you need to compare the string surrounded by commas to the input surrounded by commas.

```
IF CHARINDEX(',CompanyNav,', ',' + @VisitedWebParts + ',') > 0
BEGIN
  PRINT 'It exists!'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  PRINT 'It does not exist!'
END
```

Comment: What if CompanyNav happens to be the first word in the string , it would not be preceded by comma. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That's why I added `',' + @string + ','`... did you try it?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - you forgot to escape the single quote in "it doesn't exist"

Comment: CompanyNav does not exist and yet it says it exists

Comment: I get it does not exist. But the problem is almost certainly because your string is declared as 255 but it is actually longer than 255. Make sure you size your variables large enough because you're a victim here of silent truncation.

Comment: @SaiBand: Nice job breaking the page. Please edit your code into your question and **not** put it in a comment.

Comment: @Aaron: Wow! didnt realize that it went longer than 255. That was great. For large strings what do you think might be an ideal size.